# How to check if UIImage has transparency

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I use this function to detect if UIImage has transparency:

```
extension UIImage {
  public func isTransparent() -> Bool {
    guard let alpha: CGImageAlphaInfo = self.cgImage?.alphaInfo else { return false }
    return alpha == .first || alpha == .last || alpha == .premultipliedFirst || alpha == .premultipliedLast
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried it with a png Image with no transparency but it still return true.

Loop for each pixel is not a good idea because it's too expensive i guess.
Any idea how to check if UIImage has transparency, like this image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJh98.png)

Comment: Please provide the image your method does not work for.

Comment: @de images from clipboard when you press cmd + shift + 4 to take screenshot.

Comment: You can inspect the png like this `sips -g all image.png` to figure out the image properties. I just checked a cmd-shift-4 screenshot and it actually has an alpha channel (despite it not being used). I guess that is what your code tests for.

Answer (score 3):

You asked about Swift. Menaim gave a useful answer, but in Objective-C.

Here is a Swift version:

```
extension UIImage {
    var hasAlpha: Bool {
        guard let alphaInfo = self.cgImage?.alphaInfo else {return false}
        return alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.none &&
            alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst &&
            alphaInfo != CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast
    }
}
```

I just tested the above on a PNG image with no alpha channel and it worked.

Here is a PNG image with no alpha channel (Assuming SO's site preserves it...)
[image: PNG image with no alpha]

Comment: Thank you! I tried it works with most png, but not with screenshot from Mac OS. I don't know why.
Maybe because screenshot created by MacOS do have alpha layer but not use it and that make the code return true

Comment: You are using AND operators which looks wrong to me!

Comment: Nope, that's the correct usage in that case: "It has alpha if its not TypeOneWithNoAlpha AND it's not TypeTwoWithNoAlpha AND it's not TpyeThreeWithNoAlpha"

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be good and working without issues but you can check out this one as well:

```
- (BOOL)hasAlpha : (UIImage*) img
{
    CGImageAlphaInfo alpha = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(img.CGImage);
    return (
            alpha == kCGImageAlphaFirst ||
            alpha == kCGImageAlphaLast ||
            alpha == kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst ||
            alpha == kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
            );

}
```

Comment: It's basically the same but in Objective C.
As i said, the code doesn't work for me. A made a screenshot of my desktop and send to this function as Parameter, it return true

Answer (score 1):

I've updated Menaim's answer for swift and it works as intended.

```
extension UIImage {
  public var hasAlpha: Bool {
    guard let alphaInfo = self.cgImage?.alphaInfo else { return false }
    switch alphaInfo {
    case .none, .noneSkipLast, .noneSkipFirst:
      return false
    default:
      return true
    }
  }
}
```